# Take Picture, then edit saved picture problem!

Tags: android, android-camera

I am very new to programming and am attempting to make an app using the onboard cameras hardware, my intent is to take a picture; then when you click save that picture is brought up in a new activity to be edited... I have looked for a couple of days on how to best use the cameras hardware... I was told `startActivity(new Intent( android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE));` followed would initialize the camera the easiest... I have gotten the camera to initiate and even save the picture but my problem lies with; once I press save on the camera, the camera activity reloads instead of kicking the saved picture to a new activity where it can be edited... I know I may sound like a complete noob, and I am but if anyone understands this and can help I would be so appreciative.

Answer (score 4):

Adam,

In my app I use the following code to Launch the camera:

```
public void imageFromCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    mImageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"MyApp",  
            "PIC"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
    mSelectedImagePath = mImageFile.getAbsolutePath();
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mImageFile));
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}
```

This will save the image to the path `mSelectedImagePath` which is `/sdcard/MyApp/<systemtime>.jpg`.

Then you capture the return of the `IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent in `onActivityResult` and launch your activity to edit the image from there!

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch(requestCode) {
        case TAKE_PICTURE:
                    //Launch ImageEdit Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(this, ImageEdit.class);
                    i.putString("imgPath", "mSelectedImagePath");
                    startActivity(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @willytate I really appreciate the help, I guess I just dont get it.. when I input this coding I get all kinds of errors not solved by imports and when I think I have it it fixed; I run it through the USB debugging on my phone and as soon as I click the button to start the activity I keep getting unexpected error program has stopped please try again.

Comment: Could you edit your original question to add your code?  I may be able to assist better that way.

Comment: @willytate I'd rather not, just for fear of looking like an idiot.. Heres what I am trying to do in leimens terms. Press a button on mymenu.xml file that then sends you to the camera where you take a picture, have a choice to use the picture or retake it....then once you choose it< I want that image to be pulled up on the next screen where it can be edited.... Like I said I am really new to this so maybe Im just not sure where what supposed to go.. If you could explain what you think my problem is Id be more than willing to barter my graphic talents to you if need be... Thanks again

Comment: If you place the call to `imageFromCamera()` in your `onClickListener()` for your button, then he code I posted should all that. I've commented where you need to launch your image edit `Activity`.  Unfortunately, if you don't post code or error messages I can't really help much more :-\.  I wouldn't NOT post for fear of looking like an idiot, we were all beginners once.

Comment: the problem im running into is ...  The method onActivityResult(int, int, Intent) is undefined for the type Object

Comment: @willytate I guess I am not sure where to put the image edit activity and what parameters to use.

Comment: Adam, I added code to launch your `ImageEdit` activity assuming the class is called `ImageEdit`